# Will insert work if Live nodes are less than replication factor in Cassandra ?

Tags: cassandra, insert, replication, datastax

i have 2 cassandra node i want to give replication factor of 2 . If one node is not up will it not insert ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using low [consistency level](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dml_config_consistency_c.html) for write('ANY', 'ONE'), insert will be successful even if a node is down.